# remove squid clearly

Tags: debian, squid, apt, remove

I'm hardly trying to remove squid completly, to reinstall it clearly. (Debian 6).
So i used as root:

```
apt-get remove --purge squid
apt-get remove --purge squid3
```

but

```
find / -name squid*
```

returns

```
/var/cache/squid
/var/lib/dpkg/info/squid-cgi.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/squidclient.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/squid-cgi.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/squidclient.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/squid-cgi.list
/var/spool/squid
/etc/squid3
/etc/squid3/squid.conf.orig
/etc/squid
/etc/logcheck/ignore.d.workstation/squid
/etc/logcheck/ignore.d.paranoid/squid
/etc/logcheck/ignore.d.server/squid
/usr/share/doc/squid-cgi
/usr/share/doc/squidclient
/usr/share/man/man1/squidclient.1.gz
/usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/squid.vim
/usr/bin/squidclient
```

Besides the Log and the dpkg files. Should i remove some of this files/folders to be able to work without old issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`squidclient` and `squid-cgi` are separate packages, uninstall them too? :)
`apt-get remove --purge squidclient squid-cgi` should do the trick.

To check what package owns/installed a specific file, type: `dpkg -S /usr/bin/squidclient` for example.

Comment: I added `remove` to your command

Answer (score 1):

Using aptitude is even easier:

```
sudo aptitude purge ~nsquid
```

It will remove every package that contains squid in its name.

Answer (score -1):

And copy backup squid.conf after

- Remove squid

  ```
  apt-get remove --purge squid
  apt-get remove --purge squid3
  ```
- Install squid

  ```
  apt-get install squid
  apt-get install squid3
  ```
- Copy the file squid.conf directory squid